# Set seed for all python project

Tags: python, environment-variables, python-venv, random-seed

I have a problem with setting the seed in my project.
What I do (00_seed.py):

```
    import numpy as np
    import random
    import os
    import argparse
    import yaml
    

    def seed_everything(config_path):
        config = yaml.safe_load(open(config_path))
        seed = config['model']['seed']
        os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(seed)
        random.seed(seed)
        np.random.seed(seed)  

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        args_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        args_parser.add_argument('--config', dest='config', required=True)
        args = args_parser.parse_args()
        seed_everything(config_path=args.config)
```

where in params.yaml I fix seed=7. Then I run `venv/bin/python3.10 src/pipelines/00_seed.py --config=params.yaml`.

But `printenv PYTHONHASHSEED` return None.

where did I make a mistake?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Environment variables are inherited by child processes. Changing them doesn't have any effect on the parent process.